# Wysihtml5 not working, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).wysihtml5 is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

This is my application.html.erb. I think I have all the proper files but it is not recognizing ".wysihtml5" function.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script src="javascripts/wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: I think you need read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html first

Answer (score 1):

You don't add jquery on your script. Be sure jquery is added on your script other wise $ selector does't work.